# Aplicativo reinicia quando muda a orientação (rotacionado)?

Tags: java, android

Eu fiz isto no meu app:

- onCreate:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  ...
  ```
- instancias:

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);//Salva Activity
      siteWebView.saveState(outState);//Salva WebView
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);//Restaura o Activity
      siteWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);//Restaura o WebView
  }
  ```

E no manifest eu usei:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="br.com.foo.bar">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quiser que o Android não recrie a Activity toda vez que rotacionar o celular, basta colocar no Manifest, dentro da tag activity, o código:

```
<activity android:name=".MinhaActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

Na documentação oficial [que está aqui](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges) você pode encontrar um trecho (último paragrafo) que orienta (não explicitamente) a usar o `configChanges`.

Podes pesquisar também pelo `isChangingConfigurations` que está disponível a partir da versão HONEYCOMB do Android.

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
    @Override
    public boolean isChangingConfigurations() {
        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
            Log.i("DEBUG", "Orientation changed api >= 11 ");
            return super.isChangingConfigurations();    
        }else {
            Log.i("DEBUG", "Orientation changed api < 11 ");
            return IsconfigChange; 
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(isChangingConfigurations()){
            Log.i("DEBUG", "isChangingConfirgurations OnStop Called");
        }  else{
            Log.i("DEBUG", "OnStop Called");
        }
    }
```

A algum tempo atrás um professor meu, de android, mencionou que o fato dele chamar o onCreate, é porque lá e posto o layout para landscape e portrait, e quando fazemos (layouts com landscape podem ser postos na pasta layout-land que quando o celular estiver em paisagem, será carregado automaticamente) - e que segundo o meu professor, o onCreate não deveria fazer nada mais que carregar o layout e inicializar uma ou outra variável.

Comment: vou testar, gostei da dica do `@TargetApi`, ajudará em outras tarefas (se bem que só vou criar apps pro android4.2), obrigado por enquanto

Comment: Faça um teste cara, vê como melhor se encaixa pra ti, talvez não ajude e tenha que optar pelo configChanges, mas tomara que dê certo! Abraços!

Comment: Se você colocar o Log.i() no onResume, onCreate, ele dispara aqueles métodos mesmo com o configChanges()?

Comment: Eu cheguei a ter esse problema a algum tempo, e lembro que na época não era necessário para o projeto ter tela em landscape. Testa com o @TargetApi.
Ah, mas quando você colocou o configChanges, colocou na tua activity ou na activity geral do projeto? Tenta colocar em uma activity a parte.

Comment: Testei com mais atenção e deu certo, a unica coisa que adicionei foi o `"keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`, veja na minha pergunta, eu errei o local, o correto era adicionar `<activity ...>`, mas por falta de atenção minha eu adicionei no `<Android ...>`, obrigado Carlos.